# bypassing port blocked on domain firewall using another machine

Tags: proxy, streaming, firewall

I'd like to listen to online radio which runs on a port that is being blocked on our company's FW. (The radio changes its URL:port from time to time and I don't want to ask our admin to open another port each time this happens.)

I have my own server running outside that FW which I could use for this. If I could use Apache for such "stream forwarding" it would be great as it's running on that server already. I was thinking **proxy** or **reverse proxy** might be the answer, but I'm not sure they actually do what I need. Or is this some kind of tunneling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a discussion of using vlc to forward rtp streams is here: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=60690

not sure you can do it with apache, but i doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

So, using the reverse proxy on Apache kinda works ([this helped me a lot](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)) but there are periodical short drop-outs in the audio stream, which is probably due the fact that this functionality is not supposed for streaming data. Setting *ProxyReceiveBufferSize* or *ProxyIOBufferSize* does not help.